# MediaCodec - can an encoder's input Surface receive SurfaceTextures from two decoders' output Surfaces?

Tags: android, android-mediacodec

I'm working on an algorithm to concatenate two videos together in MediaCodec based on the usual [ExtractDecodeEditEncodeTest CTS test](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/jb-mr2-release/tests/tests/media/src/android/media/cts/ExtractDecodeEditEncodeMuxTest.java), and I'm particularly interested in this part of the code:

```
outputSurface.awaitNewImage();
outputSurface.drawImage();
inputSurface.setPresentationTime(videoDecoderOutputBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs * 1000);
inputSurface.swapBuffers();
```

Where `outputSurface` is the decoder's output surface and `inputSurface` is the encoder's input surface.

Suppose I have two MediaExtractors and two MediaCodecs acting as decoders and a single encoder with a preset format, can I just do the same in that second decoder's loop?

```
secondOutputSurface.awaitNewImage();
secondOutputSurface.drawImage();
inputSurface.setPresentationTime(prevSegmentEndNanos + videoDecoderOutputBufferInfo.presentationTimeUs * 1000);
inputSurface.swapBuffers();
```

Where `prevSegmentEndNanos` is the previous decoder's last buffer's timestamp right before it finishes decoding. `inputSurface` is the very same encoder's surface.

Would this be possible?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that should work just fine.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. By the way, can two decoders really transfer data to one encoder with that method as long as it's done sequentially?

Comment: Yes. You could (with some more complicated code) even take the output from two decoders at once, mix/blend them and feed into an encoder (by using some more advanced drawing than the current `drawImage()`). You just need to make sure that both decoders decode into outputs within the same EGL context. The `awaitNewImage()` part becomes more complex in those cases though.

Comment: If I understand correctly, I need to define some more vertices for blitting rects for the `drawImage()` part, right? Do I also need a separate loop for the second decoder that starts right after the first one ends?